# Fundamental difference between Azure Event Hub and Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

Apart from Azure service bus uses Topics and Azure Event Hub is based on Events - is there any Fundamental difference between Azure Event Hub and Azure Service Bus?

To me, there is no real difference between events and messages as both are just a different type of Json.

Comment: I would suggest starting with the documentation, which goes into quite a bit of detail, and even compares the two. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here, as you're really asking for documentation (or potentially opinions, regarding when to use one or the other).

Comment: I think Event hub is something like Kafka (massive data, high throughput, low latency) while service bus is something like traditional MQ (asyncrhonize send/reveive fewer message between different services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are dealing with JSON in both services, there is fundamentally difference between the two.

Azure Event Hubs focuses more on event streaming whereas Azure Service Bus is more focused on high-value enterprise messaging, which denotes Azure service is focused on messages rather than events.

In azure service bus With a topic, every consumer that subscribed to the topic will get each message which means each message is picked up by only 1 consumer. In case of event hub you can have multiple consumers.

You can read from the docs page [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services)

Comment: This really is a documentation-request question. And I don't think it's justified posting a high-level answer with a small subset of differences. Best to just add a comment (with doc link). The question is off-topic based on current site guidelines.

Comment: Not clearly explained.

Comment: I think "every consumer that subscribed to the topic will get each message which means each message is picked up by only 1 consumer" is worded poorly or maybe I have misunderstanding.

From the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions) it says:

"Publisher sends a message to a topic and **one or more subscribers receive a copy of the message**, depending on filter rules set on these subscriptions."

Because messages are COPIED, I thought EACH subscriber would receive the message to topic